# How do I reference (what is the syntax I have to use) to get the data of my Profile2 custom fields?

Tags: entities, users

I have used the Profile2 module (D7) and created some custom fields for my users. One of those fields (for example) is "field_company" with the label "Company."

Now I am using a computed field (*Company*) on a content type (*Games*). When user creates a *Game*, I want my computed field *Company* to be computed/populated automatically, based on the "field_company" field I have set in my profile2.

I am trying to find how to get that information. This is as far I got, so far, but it doesn't work.

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = "";
$name=$profile2->field_onoma[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']; 
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $name;
```

Comment: this is what I am using:                         $entity_field[0]['value'] = "";                   $name=$profile2->field_company[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']; $entity_field[0]['value'] = $name;

Answer (score 1):

You should use the field_view_field() function. Have a look at the follwing page for more information:
http://coder1.com/articles/printing-or-rendering-node-field-or-profile2-field-drupal-7

Comment: Lance, that in of itself is almost worth upgrading to D7 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($profile2,true) . '</pre>');
```

or changing $profile2 to whatever variable is in your code you want described is a great way of seeing what's going on...

Comment: Works less complicated if you use the Devel Module. This allows you to print almost anything with the dpm() (and others) function. Very handy for debugging.

Comment: Agreed, but I didn't want to suggest a yam (adding yet another module :) to him at this point