# drupal 7 add custom fields to profile2

Tags: 7, users

Step One

I am wondering the best approach to add custom fields to the profile2 module. I saw how to get data from a custom field [How do I reference (what is the syntax I have to use) to get the data of my Profile2 custom fields?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/how-do-i-reference-what-is-the-syntax-i-have-to-use-to-get-the-data-of-my-prof). But I am not sure how  to add the fields. What hook do i need to use. I cannot find a particular page for using the profile2 module. Could someone post a code snippet. I have used the form API so I have knowledge of constructing particular entities which I think is what fields are called in Drupal 7. 
I just though I could use the text field and integer fields that already exists and then insert these fields into the eCommerce table.

I can retrieve the field for firstname

```
function test_first_name()
   {


$uid =3;

   // calls the user_load functions
   $account = user_load($uid); 
   // now pass the account the variable to the function profile2_load_by_user
   $profile = profile2_load_by_user($account);
   //var_dump( $profile); // drupal_render(field_view_field('profile2', 
   $print_first_name =  drupal_render(field_view_field('profile2',  
   $profile['main_profile'], 'field_first_name'));
   print $print_first_name;



}
```

I have just added the product_name into my members profile as well as a product_price .I want to update the ecommerce module with the relevent fields. Does anyone know a way to insert relevent fields into the commerce tables.

I discovered the API for profile2
http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!profile2!profile2.api.php/7

```
 function mymodule_form_profile2_form_alter($form)
 {
 }
```

I am wondering if i can just use the Subscriptions and recurring payments an integrate it into profile2.

Comment: You can use hook_form_alter !

Comment: I'm using the `admin/structure/profiles` page to add fields but I'm unsure if that's what your looking for.

Comment: My plan was to add fields to the commerce table and I wasn't sure how to do that. I then though why not add a standard text field and other basic data field types and update the commerce table which is relevant to adding a product.